# COM Port Loopback test

Tags: c++, visual-studio, serial-port, uart

I'm trying to send data using C++ via the "WriteFile" API and receive it via the "ReadFile" API. I'm using an FTDI chip and I'm connecting the RX pin to the TX pin, so for example if i were to use putty, I can send 'A' and receive 'A' right back.

My problem is, when I try to do this:

```
write(myPort, 'A');    // A is  the sent character
read(myPort, &retVal);  // retVal is a pointer to the character I wanna receive.
```

cout << "received data: " << retVal << endl;

I get garbage. But when I open readFile first and THEN send a character from, let's say, an external source like a microP, then it does work.

My problem is apparently, then, that when I say "writeFile" and then run "readFile" the information is already gone and readFile returns garbage. Is there a way to keep the stuff from "writeFile" on the input buffer so that I have tim to open readFile and then read that? The reason is that i have a camera sending data through UART too fast and readFile says there's nothing there. I will greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: read inside separate thread ... also check if your garbage data is not just timeouted read. for example st retVal to 0 before ... if timeout breaks the receiving then retVal should be still 0, alsoyou can meassure the time that read COMport takes ... and compare it to timeout value if ti its too close to it then throw it away ... Also make sure that no other process is not reading your data at the same time as you ... (data will not get lost from buffer instead they can be read by someone else)

Comment: and also there is the thing of setting COM port communication protocol ... some USB<->COM reductions can not handle all configurations ... if yours does not match the FTDI chip of yours then that can be the reason of your problems ...